# Instantiation and Particles in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a question. Currently, I'm working with particle systems within Unity. I instantiate them into the scene then edit some parameters (basically just the colour). The issue is what I change on the clone I also change on the original prefab. As you can imagine this isn't what I want. So my question is does anyone know how to do this without editing the prefab as well?

```
GameObject l = Instantiate((GameObject)(Resources.Load("MultiSpell/Electric/Lightning")));
        ParticleSystem ps = l.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();

        Gradient eGrad = createGradLightning(spellType.spellColour);

        var psColor = ps.colorOverLifetime;
        psColor.enabled = true;
        psColor.color = eGrad;

        var psTrails = ps.trails;
        psTrails.colorOverLifetime = eGrad;



Gradient createGradLightning(Color col)
{
    Gradient grad = new Gradient();

    GradientColorKey col1 = new GradientColorKey();
    col1.color = col;
    col1.time = 0;

    GradientColorKey col2 = new GradientColorKey();
    col2.color = Color.black;
    col2.time = 0.9f;

    GradientAlphaKey alp1 = new GradientAlphaKey();
    alp1.time = 1;
    alp1.alpha = 0;

    GradientAlphaKey alp2 = new GradientAlphaKey();
    alp2.time = 0;
    alp2.alpha = 0f;

    grad.SetKeys(new GradientColorKey[2] { col1, col2 }, new GradientAlphaKey[2] {alp1, alp2});
    return grad;
}
```

Comment: Looks right to me. Are you sure you're not changing your gradient?

Comment: Or are you messing with any sharedMaterials instead of changing their material?

Comment: I'm changing the gradient, that's the thing I want to create a clone of the system so I can change it without changing the original prefab

Comment: I'm not messing with shared materials or anything, just the particle system component of the instantiated gameobject

Comment: I am just copy your code, and it works fine. Problem is not in the code.

Comment: So when you use the code it doesn't edit the prefab at all?

Comment: It shouldn't. your reference is to an Instantiated instance, not to the prefab itself.

Answer (score 0):

Some common causes for editing the prefab instead of (or with) the instance:

1. You have a direct reference to the prefab hooked up to a script in
   your editor (possible, if you have another script!)
2. Your reference is to `Resource.Load` instead of `Instantiate` (not the
   case here)
3. You're editing a material directly, rather than the instantiated
   version on (See (1) and (2))

Comment: I've edited my code to show my create gradient function as well, maybe that can help pinpoint it?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Your changes must be elsewhere